# Integral of $\sin(x)/x$ over a triangle

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to determine the value of following Integral:

> Let $D$ be the triangle with vertices $(0, 0)$, $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$, and $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Calculate the integral of the function $f(x, y) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ over $D$.

I know that the function is not Lebesgue-integrable and the Intgeral is defined over the Si(x) function. But there should be a way to integrate it over a 2 dimensional integral.

Comment: *Hint:* Integrate with respect to $y$ first ...

Comment: @MartinR now I have, $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx $

Comment: No. Note that $D$ is a triangle, not a square.

Comment: @MartinR $\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx $, this should be correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle $D$ is the set
$$
 D = \{ (x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid 0 < y < x < \frac \pi 2\}
$$
so that the integral of $f$ over $D$ is
$$
 \int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\int_0^x f(x, y) \,dy \right) \, dx \, .
$$
But $f$ does not depend on $y$, so that the inner integral is simply
$$
 x \cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \sin(x)
$$
and the outer integral is now easy to compute.